# Access denied to Wordpress admin panel (nginx / ubuntu)

Tags: nginx, wordpress

**Setup:** nginx/1.4.6, Ubuntu/14.04.3 LTS, Wordpress/4.5.4

I'm running Wordpress from a subdirectory (followed this article: [Using a pre-existing subdirectory install](https://codex.wordpress.org/Giving_WordPress_Its_Own_Directory#Using_a_pre-existing_subdirectory_install)) and the only way I found to make the site work is having this as part of my nginx config:

```
location / {
    try_files $uri /wordpress$uri/ /wordpress/index.php?$args;
}
```

... but with it I ***can't access the admin panel***. With any other nginx config I see the HTML content, but I get 404's for every external asset (css, images, js, etc).

I tried many different config's with no results following this posts (among many others):

- [Nginx Config - I can't access WordPress admin area](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6154879/nginx-wordpress-in-a-subdirectory-what-data-should-be-passed)
- [Nginx - wordpress in a subdirectory, what data should be passed?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6154879/nginx-wordpress-in-a-subdirectory-what-data-should-be-passed)

**Current nginx config:**

```
server {
    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80 default_server ipv6only=on;

    root /usr/share/nginx/html;
    index index.php;

    server_name mysite.com;

    location / {
        #try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args;
        #try_files $uri /wordpress$uri/ /wordpress/index.php?$args;
    }

    location /wordpress {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /wordpress/index.php?$args;
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
        try_files $uri =404;
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
        fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        include fastcgi_params;
    }
}
```

Comment: You don't need any special nginx configuration for this. You should revert it to normal. But you do need to make sure your [home and siteurl](https://codex.wordpress.org/Changing_The_Site_URL) are set correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's the location setup I use for running wordpress in a "blog" subdirectory. more_clear_headers requires the correct module compiled into Nginx.

```
location / {
    # If the file can't be found try adding a slash on the end - it might be
    # a directory the client is looking for. Then try the Wordpress blog URL
    # this might send a few requests to PHP that don't need to go that way
    try_files $uri $uri/ /blog/index.php?$args;
    more_clear_headers Server; more_clear_headers "Pragma"; more_clear_headers "Expires";
}
```

This part is helpful

```
# Add trailing slash to */wp-admin requests.
rewrite /blog/wp-admin$ $scheme://$host$uri/ permanent;
```

This isn't necessary for most, but I change a bunch of headers for non-admin pages so this makes sure the default headers are passed through.

```
# Wordpress admin caching headers are set correctly, for pages and resources. The only reason we define
# this block separately is to avoid messing with the headers in the main php block.
# This is probably unnecessary because of the skip_cache variable and may be removed
location ~* wp-admin {
    fastcgi_keep_conn on;

    fastcgi_pass php56-fpm;
    include        fastcgi_params;
    fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
    fastcgi_index index.php;
 }
```

I have a [Wordpress/Nginx tutorial](https://www.photographerstechsupport.com/tutorials/hosting-wordpress-on-aws-tutorial-pt1-introduction-configuration-downloads/#wpmu-nginx-configuration-files) you might find useful. It includes config files you can download, though I don't think I actually include this pattern of Wordpress in a subdirectory - not 100% sure.